# Drawing a polygon in Google Earth using coordinates for each point

Tags: google-earth

Is there an easy way to draw land plots in Google Earth using coordinates for each point of the polygon?

Comment: So you're saying you have lat/long coordinates for each corner and you just want to create a polygon from those points? Is this a one-off operation or do you have a bulk list of land plots you're trying to do all at once?

Comment: I have many plots that I want to put on google earth, most are usually rectangular, I have calculated the lat/long coordinates for each corner of the polygon, but in google earth I can't find any option to position the corners using the coordinates.

Comment: My guess is it would be easiest to create a KML file and load that. Could be done by text editing, or you could use QGIS to plot the points, make the shapes, and then export a KML. A couple of resources: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/VwvLfRAA9zU and https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/point-to-polygon-part-i/

Comment: Those resources are not helpful. The first one, the links are not functioning. The 2nd one, it's even more confusing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143332)

Answer (score 4):

The way I solved this was as follows: I created a semi-rectangular (or any other shaped form) polygon in Google Earth and then saved as kml file. In notepad++ I opened and looked for the place where all the lat long information was stored. In my case longitude was followed by latitude and then by altitude (0s). All values were presented as decimal degrees separated by commas. Every single point was separated by a space. I formatted my very long and irregular polygon following the same format and then copied into the kml file I just created so the previous longitude, latitude, altitude information was now substituted by the new one. Saved and opened in Google Earth Pro and then I was able to change colours and other parts.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Jorge wrote. KML to TXT and edit section between coordinates. Editing quasi-rectangular shape to rectangular. Picture shows values before editing.

[image: Values before editing]